# Can a DNN Module written in VS 2005 be used in latest version of DNN which is written in VS2008

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-module

Can a DNN Module written in VS 2005 be used in latest version of DNN which is written in VS2008

We have created a DNN module in VS2005 -- which used to work fine with the DNN version we had then 4.*

Now we are installing a fresh copy of DNN which we believe requires/opens in VS2008 and above (.net 3.5 sp1)?

Can we simply copy the existing module files into the correct folders (aka App_Code and Desktop Modules) and expect the module to work fine?

Answer (score 3):

Just moving from VS 2005 to 2008 should not cause your module to break.  The main thing to be concerned about is whether your module is using some piece of core DNN functionality that has been deprecated in DNN 5.x. That is fairly unlikely, though. I have a large custom module that I wrote for DNN 4.3 that I have never modified and it still runs fine on DNN 5.6.

Answer (score 0):

The main thing that we've found that breaks when moving from DNN 4 to DNN 5 is if you're dependent on the database structure of DNN (i.e. querying the Users, Tabs, Portals, etc tables), those saw some significant changes in DNN 5.2, 5.3, & 5.5.  In general, you should be using the API instead of the database to interface with DNN.  If you need to get into the database, use the views instead of the tables.